# CSS: Set color of `strong` inside specific paragraph class

Tags: html, css

I am a bit of a newb in CSS styling. 
I have a stylesheet in which image captions `<p class="caption">` are light-on-darkl while normal text is dark-on-white. This works fine in general, but somewhere else in the stylesheet is set `strong {color: #XXX}`, which seems to override the color I set in the `.caption` tag in my CSS.

What I would want to do was something like:

```
p.caption strong {color:#YYY}
```

...to give `<strong>` its own color inside the captions, but this is clearly not the correct syntax.  How do I do this?

The html is autogenerated and I am not too familiar with the code that does it, so preferrably CSS-only solution.

Comment: Try `p.caption > strong {color:#YYY !important}`

Comment: Simply writing `p.caption > strong {color:#YYY}` worked.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax `p.caption strong {color:#YYY}` is correct, naturally assuming that `#YYY` is replaced by a real color value. If it does not work, then there is some other style sheet that overrides it using a more specific selector and/or the `!important` specifier. You need to check what the other style sheet does and modify your rule so that it “win”.

Developer tools (which you typically open by pressing the F12 key) let you see which style sheet rules apply to an element.

If another style sheet sets just `strong {color:#XXX}`, it won’t win your rule. It may have `strong {color:#YYY !important}`, in which case you too need to use `!important` *and* a more specific selector. Using just `p.caption strong {color:#YYY} !important` may help, but it does not if the other style sheet has a similar rule, in which case you need make your selector more specific. This might result in a somewhat artificial selector like `html body p.caption strong {color:#YYY}`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the original CSS, try overriding this value:

```
p.caption strong {color:#YYY !important}
```